# How to store the arraylist in ormlite database

Tags: android, database

I am trying to save the arraylist of class objects into the ormlite database , but it is giving the error , java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No fields have a DatabaseField annotation in class java.util.ArrayList

my code is

```
@DatabaseTable
public class ManageModelDetails {

@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
private int id;

@DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
private ArrayList<ModelDetails> listModelDetails;

// ===============================================
public ManageModelDetails() {
    super();
}

// ===============================================

public ManageModelDetails(int id, ArrayList<ModelDetails> listModelDetails) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.listModelDetails = listModelDetails;
}

// ===============================================

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setModelList(ArrayList<ModelDetails> listModelDetails) {
    this.listModelDetails = listModelDetails;
}

public ArrayList<ModelDetails> getModelList() {
    return listModelDetails;
}

}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to use Foreign Collections. Take a look here:

- [Foreign Collections](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#Foreign-Collection)
- [Another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272155/persisting-a-collection-class-with-ormlite-in-android)

Comment: That's true, if the order of the list doesn't matter (the question mentions an ArrayList). If it does, then the arraylist should be stored in a custom way.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to save an ArrayList of objects to ORMLite the easiest way is this:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
private SerializedList<MyObject> myObjects;
```

and to get my list of objects:

```
public List<MyObject> getMyObjects() {
  return myObjects;
}
```

and here is SerializedList:

```
public class SerializedList<E> extends ArrayList<E> implements Serializable {
}
```

Comment: what is SerializedList? from which library?

Comment: actually that was just an ArrayList that implements Serializable, see updated answer